# how to access the textbox of dynamically created table in user control page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, user-controls

Actually i'm creating web template using asp.net and c#.
in my `user control` page i have to create the table dynamically. i just read the data from XML file then retrieve the name and number of columns and rows of each table. while i'm creating the table i assign the name and id to each cell. because i have one row including some `textbox` for adding the data to database. but after i have created the table i can not access to the `textbox` cells based on id to get their data and insert it to database.
my dynamic table code is:

```
public void CreateAddDynamicTable()
{
    XmlDocument xDocRead = new XmlDocument();
    xDocRead.Load(Server.MapPath("ModuleTemp.xml"));
    string xModuleName = hid_ChooseModule.Value;
    XmlNode xColCounter = xDocRead.SelectSingleNode("ModuleTemp/" + xModuleName + "/List");
    int colCount = xColCounter.ChildNodes.Count;

    int nonPkCounter = 0;
    string[] nonPrimaryKey = new string[100];
    string[] nonPkNewDataTemp = new string[100];

    for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++)
    {
        if (xDocRead.SelectSingleNode("ModuleTemp/" + xModuleName + "/Add/TableColumn" + i).Attributes.GetNamedItem("IsPrimaryKey").Value == "N")
        {
            nonPrimaryKey[nonPkCounter] = xDocRead.SelectSingleNode("ModuleTemp/" + xModuleName + "/Add/TableColumn" + i).Attributes.GetNamedItem("Name").Value;
            nonPkCounter++;
        }
    }

    ph_Uc_AddModule.Controls.Clear();

    // Fetch the number of Rows and Columns for the table 
    // using the properties
    int tblRows = nonPkCounter;
    int tblCols = 2;

    // Create a Table and set its properties 
    Table tbl = new Table();
    // Add the table to the placeholder control
    ph_Uc_AddModule.Controls.Add(tbl);
    // Now iterate through the table and add your controls 
    for (int i = 0; i < tblRows; i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < tblCols; j++)
        {
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            Label td_Add_Header = new Label();
            TextBox td_Add = new TextBox();

            if (j == 0)
            {
                td_Add_Header.Text = nonPrimaryKey[i];
                td_Add_Header.ID = "lb" + (i + 1) + "_header_AddModule";

                // Add the control to the TableCell
                tc.Controls.Add(td_Add_Header);
                tc.CssClass = "td_Header_AddModule";
            }
            else
            {
                td_Add.Text = "";
                td_Add.ID = "tb" + (i + 1) + "_AddModule";
                // Add the control to the TableCell
                tc.Controls.Add(td_Add);
                tc.CssClass = "td_Tb_AddModule";
            }

            // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        }
        // Add the TableRow to the Table
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
}
```

my user control page which is contain a `PlaceHolder` is as below:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pn_Uc_TModule" runat="server">

<asp:Table runat="server" ID="table_Uc_TModule" CssClass="table_Uc_TModule" Width="100%">
 <asp:TableRow runat="server" VerticalAlign="Top" Height="50px">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="" CssClass="btn_Add_Active" OnClick="btn_AddNew_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel_NewItem" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="btn_Cancel_New" OnClick="btn_Cancel_AddNew" Visible="false" />

                    <asp:Table runat="server" ID="table_Uc_AddModule" Visible="false">
                        <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                            <asp:TableCell runat="server" >

                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph_Uc_AddModule" runat="server">
                                </asp:PlaceHolder>

                            </asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
                            <asp:TableCell runat="server" CssClass="td_Tb_AddModule" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_Insert" runat="server" OnClick="Uc_AddModule_ItemInsert" Text="" CssClass="btn_Add" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" OnClick="Uc_AddModule_Clear" Text="" CssClass="btn_Clear" />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableRow>
                    </asp:Table>

                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
</asp:Panel>
```

i'm using below method in my insert function at the code behind to access the data inserted at the `textbox`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= nonPkCounter; i++)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (ph_Uc_AddModule.FindControl("tb" + i + "_AddModule")) as TextBox;

    }
```

i have tried `pn_Uc_TModule.FindControl("tb" + i + "_AddModule")` and also `This.ph_Uc_AddModule.FindControl("tb" + i + "_AddModule")` but still con not get the `texbox` data to insert it to database.
could you please guide me how to get it done.
appreciate your consideration.

Comment: In what event you are calling the CreateAddDynamicTable method? Init? Load?

Answer (score 1):

You should call CreateAddDynamicTable on your Init event always. That will make the viewstate make sense and asp.net will load all the values to the controls. Then you can add the textboxes to a collection and access them without using FindControl, just the references, in your Page_Load event.

Comment: first thanks for the reply, actually my template aspx page is include 3 panel. the first panel contains the main menu, second panel contain sub menus and third panel include usercontrol page. inside the usercontrol page i have add button. once the user click on the add button then i call the CreateAddDynamicTable() and create the table. then in this created table i have some textbox which the user can insert the data and submit it. once the user submit i want to get all textboxes data and insert it to database. this is the whole story. now how i can access these textboes data?

Comment: mmhhh I suggest always create the table but make it visible=false and just set the value to true when the user clicks the button. The result will be the same, as visible=false will not create the html in the response but keep track of your controls, events and viewstate

Comment: my task is to get the data from XML file then create the table based on that information. i can not ignore this process and in some module i have more than 80 table. it's not advisable to put all the table in template page and make it visible=false or True. thanks.

Comment: Ok. you will need to create that control structure (table+textboxes) before using findcontrol. If you do that, you could just keep the references as I suggested. If you are not able to create the structure again, the you will need to check the request parameter and start playing with it, but I don't recommend it.